# Wait verify using "ExpectedConditions" does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

**UPDATED VERSION**

I'm trying to find a more dynamic way to wait for elements instead of using static wait functions like `Task.Event(2000).Wait();`

The solution to this seems to be this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/input")));
```

But when I use this function, the "ExpectedConditions" always lights up red indicating that it: "does not exist in the current context".

I've placed the function in one of my testcases:

(I am using C#/Visual Studios, Project type: Classlibrary)

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        public class MyFirstTest
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            [Test]
            public void WaitverifyTest()
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.se/");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                Task.Delay(4000).Wait();

                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/input")).SendKeys("Selenium");

                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/input")));
                element.Click();

                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//center/input")).Click();
            }
       }
   }
```

(The xpath is a location type xpath, it is valid and works in both Selenium IDE and in Visual Studios.)

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I have two suspicions:

1. My version of selenium could be too new (3.6.0.0)

According to [selenium.io](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) , ExpectedCondition was last updated in 3.1.0. Maybe it is no longer vaild. Is there someway to check this?

2. Maybe my project type is not compatible with ExpectedCondition, and therefore does not recognize it?

Comment: use ElementToBeClickable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've seen this before.

Make sure you've installed both the Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support NuGet packages for your project. You'll need the Selenium.Support package to use ExpectedConditions.

Comment: This is the one that actually answers the question/solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks man, this is really helpful. Sadly it will be deprecated soon, so anyone who's reading this, to save you some trouble just look for another way.

Comment: @Sky Luke since ExpectedConditions is deprecated now and no longer part of Selenium Support could you please change your reply?

Answer (score 6):

I resloved this way:

1: Using nuget, search for DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers,

2: Import that namespace into your class.

```
    using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

3: Then run the following code:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("element ID")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this line:

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/input")));
```

How are you able to cast Until to an IWebElement since it returns bool? I might be missing something.

But you might be able to bypass the error if you don't use ExpectedConditions, like so:

```
wait().Until( foo => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/input")).Enabled);
```

WebDriverWait takes as a parameter a function that returns a bool. You can create one within the parameters with the above code, that will return true when the element is enabled.

Comment: .Until basically just keeps trying the given function until the function returns neither null nor false, the function throws an exception, or the timeout expires. It doesn't return a bool, it returns the delegates result. The ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable returns an IWebElement, so wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(...) will either timeout, throw an exception or return the IWebElement

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` use `elementTobeClickable` method, it should work i guess

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.svt.se/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(
        By.XPath("//li[4]/a")));

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[4]/a")).Click();
```

Comment: I have changed it to ElementToBeClickable. But it does not help. It still does not regonize ExpectedConditions and says that it "does not exist in the current context". I have also updated my original post with more info.